# How do I divide so that I get a full number and a remainder

Tags: java, math, input, output

I am making a calculator project that can add, subtract, multiply, divide, and *divide with a remainder*. For example I have `75 / 4`. I need it to give me this: `18.3` or `18 R3`. Is there any way to do it? My project is here: http://pastebin.com/TQ9YtuF0.

Comment: "*Please don't put on hold because I am a beginner at both programing and stack overflow.*" That's not how it works. You can become advanced at Stackoverflow by following the guidelines and making sure your post contains everything it has to contain.

Comment: ok. sorry if it was bad, I don't know much

Comment: Then learn [ask]; it doesn't matter if you're a beginner, but you should still be able to write a question that isn't garbage.

Comment: There is lot of examples exists in the web.

Answer (score 1):

in JAVA

```
 int quotient= 75/4;
 int remainder = 75 % 4;
```

the above code is the required answers. Division "/" gives a integer quotient when used on integer. % is the simple modulo operator.

Comment: do I have to combine those 2 into a string to get the answer? Or do I just add them together?

Comment: no . you just need to write 75 % 4 for the remainder part. no need of division. Also int will be implicitly converted to string since you use System.out.println("Answer = " + answer); so dont worry just write answer= a%b; in place of                       //this is where I want it to divide with a remainder.

Comment: how do I make it so that it makes answer both the full number and the remainder?

Comment: I need it to give me a full number and a remainder like '18.3' or '18 with remainder 3'